# How to set searchview as actionbar submenu item

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, menu, android-actionbar, searchview

I need to add searchview as dropdown view in my android app.[image]

please refer the image. When I click the action bar item search view should expand from the action bar. Please help me

Comment: Make a custom XML for your ActionBar keep the search bar invisible. Then on your menu item click, just reveal it with a nice animation.

Comment: This cant be done with menu, as Skynet said you have to create custom view and apply animation to it.